# How to apply pandas dataframe.where on just one column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to add some days to a dataframe column using dataframe.where, but it behaves weirdly. Here is the dataframe, current result and expected result.

```
my_dict={'NAME':['Ravi','Raju','Alex','Ron','King','Jack'],
         'ID':[1,2,3,4,5,6],
         'MATH':[80,40,70,70,82,30],
         'ENGLISH':[81,70,40,50,60,30],
         'Result Date': ['2021-08-01', '2021-04-24', '2021-09-30', '2021-07-13', '2021-09-30', '2021-07-13'],
}
my_data = pd.DataFrame(data=my_dict)
my_data['Result Date'] = pd.to_datetime(my_data['Result Date'])

my_data['Result Date'] = my_data.where(my_data["ID"] > 5, my_data['Result Date'] + pd.Timedelta(days=14), axis=1)
```

Current result:
[image]

Expected result:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

assuming you had a typo error with Arrival time as you haven't mentioned anything about Arrival time in the my_dict

here is the updated code

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 

my_dict={'NAME':['Ravi','Raju','Alex','Ron','King','Jack'],
         'ID':[1,2,3,4,5,6],
         'MATH':[80,40,70,70,82,30],
         'ENGLISH':[81,70,40,50,60,30],
         'Result Date': ['2021-08-01', '2021-04-24', '2021-09-30', '2021-07-13', '2021-09-30', '2021-07-13'],
}
my_data = pd.DataFrame(data=my_dict)
my_data['Result Date'] = pd.to_datetime(my_data['Result Date'])

my_data['Result Date'] = np.where(my_data["ID"] > 5, my_data['Result Date'] + pd.Timedelta(days=14), None)
my_data['Result Date'] = pd.to_datetime(my_data['Result Date'])
print(my_data)
```

output:

```
NAME  ID  MATH  ENGLISH Result Date
0  Ravi   1    80       81         NaT
1  Raju   2    40       70         NaT
2  Alex   3    70       40         NaT
3   Ron   4    70       50         NaT
4  King   5    82       60         NaT
5  Jack   6    30       30  2021-07-27
```

Answer (score 0):

The code below works to get the desired result. The answer by Yashaswi K works, but we need to use another library, Numpy, but I was looking for something using Pandas.

```
my_data['Result Date'] = (my_data['Result Date'] + pd.Timedelta(days=14)).where(my_data["ID"] > 5, None )
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `where` on the specific column:

```
my_data['Result Date'] = my_data['Result Date'].where(my_data["ID"].gt(5))+pd.Timedelta(days=14)


>>> my_data
   NAME  ID  MATH  ENGLISH Result Date
0  Ravi   1    80       81         NaT
1  Raju   2    40       70         NaT
2  Alex   3    70       40         NaT
3   Ron   4    70       50         NaT
4  King   5    82       60         NaT
5  Jack   6    30       30  2021-07-27
```